# How to changes take effect on an updated Joomla Global Configuration file?

Tags: cookies, joomla

I have updated the global configuration file, I changed the cookie_path variable, and I restarted the HTTTP Server and cleared cache files from Admin Panel. But, still I get old cookie_path value on response headers.

I do not have any experience before with Joomla,  please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My client gave me a copy of the site. And I was checking the real one's headers. So, there is no such a problem.